# JMSListener escapes '.' for durable subscriptions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

With Spring JMS 4.3.19 as well as with 5.2.5 I am trying to set up a `JMSListener` for durable subscriptions:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "test", subscription = "Consumer.Test", connectionFactory = "factory")
public void receiveFromDurableSub(String message) {
    System.out.println("receiveFromTest: " + message);
}
```

But it ends up in `Consumer\\.Test`. For addresses it works somehow.

How can I avoid those backslashes?

Comment: The actual name used for the durable subscription shouldn't really matter as it will be based on the client ID and subscription name set via the JMS API. Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: In case you want to send messages to da dedicated consumer queue, you can use FQQN. If you do this by jmsTemplate, you need to add those slashes, otherwise it won't work. If you use a different client, e.g. stomp, you need just one slash instead of two. So if there would be the possibility to make it uniform, it would be better. Furthmore, the addresses do not have slashes neither, so this is somehow not uniform.

Comment: How come you need to use the FQQN? It's pretty rare that you'd ever want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMS topic subscriptions are implemented on ActiveMQ Artemis as queues. Each subscription gets it own queue.

The name of the queue depends on how the subscription is configured. The broker will take the JMS client ID (if one is configured), the JMS subscription name (if one is configured), and the JMS subscription's durability to construct the name of the underlying subscription queue. The broker uses the `.` character to concatenate all these piece of information together to compose the final name. See [the related source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-jms-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQDestination.java#L167) for more details on that bit.

In order to be able to *decompose* this name into its constituent parts later any uses of the `.` character in the client ID or subscription name have to be escaped.

Since you're using `Consumer.Test` for the JMS subscription's name this will ultimately be escaped to `Consumer\\.Test` for use in the underlying subscription queue's name. The broker's use of the `.` character is not configurable in this case.

If you don't want your subscription's name to be escaped then I recommend you don't use a name with a `.` character in it (e.g. `Consumer-Test`).